# How do I configure Route53 so domain and one subdomain go to same place?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I own the domain name albunack.net and it is now under Route53 control (with NS & SOA record sets)

I have a server running on Elastic Beanstalk as albunack.elasticbeanstalk.com

In Route53 I have added a CNAME record direct.albunack.net -> albunack.elasticbeanstalk.com

On CloudFront I have created new Distribution with origin server of direct.albunack.net and alternate Cname: www.albunack.net and albunack.net

Then on route53 I have added another CNAME record www.albunack.net -> cloudfront name

But my question is how/what kind of record do I add to Route53 so that albunack.net (without the www part) also goes to the Cloudfront server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to create what's called an [alias record](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) to your CloudFront distribution.

- In your hosted zone, select **Create Record Set**
- Leave the name value empty
- Leave type to **A**
- Select **Yes** from Alias
- Click in the alias target box, your CloudFront distribution should show up.  If it doesn't, you can manually paste in your CloudFront distribution's DNS name here.
- Click Save

Comment: Thanks, seemed to have worked but kind of weird to me because it says A record is an ip address but I entered the dns name of the cloudfront distribution like you said rather than ipaddress ?

Comment: An A record *is* an IP address... but Route 53's "alias" records allow you to direct Route53 to pick up an IP address from elsewhere in the AWS ecosystem via a named reference.  It works in places where a CNAME doesn't, such as at the apex of a domain, in this case.

Comment: heh, actually it doesnt seem to be working for me however if I remove the A record set it works anyway, going to albunack.net automtically chnages to www.albunack.net !?

Comment: Ah its just my browser (firefox) converting from albunack.net to www.albunack.net, doesn't work for IExplorer - I'll give your solution another go

Comment: Ah my bad, I had recreated cloudfront distribution and hadn't added albunack.net as an alternate cname (after its not actually a cname but an alias). When I did add it and and then created alias in Route53 the cloudfront distribution was listed and after a wait of about 10 minutes for it propogate it now works testing with (Internet Explorer)